# ExtJS ComponentQuery selector for model instance, or what's the appropriate use of Models in MVC?

Tags: javascript, extjs

Maybe what I'm trying to do is against MVC, but here goes.

I have View events that I've bound to functions on my Controller.  These events update an instance of a Model that I create on Controller.init.  I want the update of the Model instance to raise events that I can bind to functions on my Controller.

What's the proper way to do this?  I call Controller.control but I don't know what to pass in for a selector.

Here's my Controller.init:

```
var me = this;

me.keysModelInstance = me.getKeysModel().create();
me.control({
    'model#keys': {
        onkeyschange: me.onKeysModelInstanceChange
    }
});
```

Here's my Model:

```
Ext.define('pronghorn_ui_keyboard.model.Keys', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: [
        {
            name: 'keys',
            type: 'string'
        }
    ],

    add: function(key) {
        this.set('keys', this.get('keys') + key);
        this.fireEvent('onkeyschange');
    },

    clear: function() {
        this.set('keys', '');
        this.fireEvent('onkeyschange');
    }

});
```

I know I can get what I want to happen with custom listeners, but that doesn't feel like the "MVC way".  Are Models just not intended to raise events?  That doesn't make sense, though.  What about Models and Stores that raise events when their Proxies get async updates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 4.1x the only object types controllers can listen to are components. Models are not component classes. Ext 4.2 adds ability to listen for Store events. 
Back in 4.1x you can also fire application level events and controllers can react to those as well.

From the part 3 of MVC [**tutorial**](http://www.sencha.com/learn/architecting-your-app-in-ext-js-4-part-3):

```
init: function() {
    ...
    // We listen for the application-wide stationstart event
    this.application.on({
        stationstart: this.onStationStart,
        scope: this
    });
},
```

fired by:

```
 this.application.fireEvent('stationstart', selection[0]);
```

Comment: I can call me.keysModelInstance.on to set up a listener with Controller.this as scope inside the Controller.init.  I guess this achieves the same thing, just not with a ComponentQuery.